# creating text to image for rendering in html src via function call

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to render an image generated by a function call in php.

I've copy pasted a function found at php for kids and found elsewhere here.

```
 function txt_to_png($textin){
  //Set the Content Type
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
  // Create Image From Existing File
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('../images/100.jpg');
  // Allocate A Color For The Text
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);
  // Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = '../fonts/lato-regular.ttf';;
  // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
  $text = "This is a sunset!"; // just hardcoding for moment
  // Print Text On Image
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);
  // Send Image to Browser
  imagejpeg($jpg_image);
  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
 }
```

I am calling the function as follows:

```
Print ('<img itemprop="image" src="');
txt_to_png($my_text_input);
Print ('">');
```

but it's not rendering the image correctly:

```
<img itemprop="image" src="�����JFIF���������&gt;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v90), default quality
���C�     

 $.' " ,#(7),01444'9="82<.342���C" ="" ="" 2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222����d�d"��������������="" �������}�!1aqa"q2���#b��r��$3br�="" %&'()*456789:cdefghijstuvwxyzcdefghijstuvwxyz�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������="" ������w�!1aqaq"2�b����="" #3r�br�="" $4�%�&'()*56789:cdefghijstuvwxyzcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������="" ��?��j(��="" (��="" (��?��"="">
```

Thanks for any help!
Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `txt_to_png` function is creating an image as a binary code. You need to add `src="somefile.php?textin=abcd` and in the `somefile.php` call your function with parameter `txt_to_png($_GET['textin]);`

Comment: thanks, yep this works. just wondering if there is anyway to keep the function unchanged and render via the src=" with some src="data:image/jpeg;base64,.....